# python asyncio result not set in task error

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I am trying to create an `asyncio` task, perform some `db query` and then a `for loop` process and get the result back in the `task`. However, in the code sample below, it seems like my `result` is not being put to `total_result.result()` but rather, just to `total_result`.

Not sure if there is any misunderstanding that I"m having regarding my implementation of `asyncio` below?

```
class DatabaseHandler:
    def __init__(self):
        self.loop = get_event_loop()
        self.engine = create_engine("postgres stuffs here")
        self.conn = self.engine.connect()

    async def _fetch_sql_data(self, query):
        return self.conn.execute(query)

    async def get_all(self, item):
        total_result = []
        if item == "all":
            data = create_task(self._fetch_sql_data("select col1 from table1;"))
        else:
            data = create_task(self._fetch_sql_data(f"select col1 from table1 where quote = '{item}';"))
        await data
        for i in data.result().fetchall():
            total_result.append(i[0])

        return total_result

    async def update(self):
        total_result = create_task(self.get_all("all"))
        print(await total_result)  # prints out the result immediately and not the task object.
        
        # this means that `total_result.result()` produces an error

loop = get_event_loop()
a = DatabaseHandler()
loop.run_until_complete(a.update())
```

I have a feeling that it is because of `total_result` being a list object. But not sure how to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

`task.result()` returns the result of your task (the return value of the wrapped coro) and not another `Task`. This means this

```py
task = asyncio.create_task(coro())
await task
result = task.result()
```

is actually equivalent to

```py
result = await coro()
```

Using tasks is especially useful, if you want to execute multiple coroutines concurrently. But as you are not doing that here, your code is a bit overcomplicated. You can just do

```py
async def get_all(self, item):
        total_result = []
        if item == "all":
            result = await self._fetch_sql_data("select col1 from table1;")
        else:
            result = await self._fetch_sql_data(f"select col1 from table1 where quote = '{item}';")

        for i in result.fetchall():
            total_result.append(i[0])

        return total_result # holds the results of your db query just as called from sync code
```